# Dynamically generated dependencies

Tags: cmake

I am trying to generate file that depends on a set of files that can
change throughout different make invocations.

To understand it better, let's show you the code:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project(demo-one C)

add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT
        "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/generated.c"
    COMMAND
        generate -o "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/generated.c"
    DEPENDS
        "$(shell generate-dependencies-list)"
    COMMENT
        "Generating generated.c"
)

add_executable(main main.c "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/generated.c")
```

So, I want to generate the file `generated.c` with the `generate`
command and this files needs to be regenerated when the files
specified by `generated-dependencies-list` command changes. As you may
notice, `generated-dependencies-list` can generate different set of
files throughout make invocations, so is not feasible to get
the result of `generated-dependencies-list` at configure time to then
pass the result to `add_custom_command`.

Actually the above code somewhat works, but it looks like a hack that
will only work for Makefile backend, also the make rule doesn't look
as what I'm expecting, after all, it's a hack:

```
generated.c: ../$(shell\ generate-dependencies-list)
```

Basically, I want this rule or something to get the same result:

```
generated.c: $(shell generate-dependencies-list)
```

Has CMake any feature to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

> when the files specified by generated-dependencies-list command changes

If the output of the command `generated-dependencies-list` depends only on this script and script's parameters then you can just add this script to `DEPENDS` sub-option:

```
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT
        "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/generated.c"
    COMMAND
        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/generate-dependencies-list"
    COMMAND
        generate -o "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/generated.c"
    DEPENDS
        "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/generate-dependencies-list"
    COMMENT
        "Generating generated.c"
)
```

Comment: Hmm... I think you didn't understand. generate-dependencies-list is a command that outputs the dependencies to build generated.c, this output can change throughout make invocations (for example, by adding a new file), note that these dependencies are used to generate generated.c but they don't necessary have to be part of the build system (they don't be to be installed)

Comment: @eagleoneraptor `generate-dependencies-list is a command that outputs the dependencies` if the output of command may change from time to time without changes in the script or script's parameters then you can't do it (at least in optimal way). That's exactly the reason why [file(GLOB...)](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/file.html) is not recommended. In this case you need to run this command every build (i.e. every make) even nothing changed.